# What are Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger's abilities counted as?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Ulamog, the Ceaseless Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlamog%2c%20the%20Ceaseless%20Hunger%5d) and my fried has [Viper's kiss](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bViper%27s%5d%2b%5bkiss%5d):

> Enchanted creature gets -1/-1, and its activated abilities can't be activated.

When Ulamog attcks is that an activated ability or or is it a creature spell that can be countered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is neither. It is a **[triggered ability](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability)**:

> **603.1.** Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect].”

Ulamog has two triggered abilities — one for when he's cast, and one for when he attacks — and [indestructible](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Indestructible), a [keyword ability](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Keyword_ability).

Viper's Kiss has no effect on any of these abilities. It will give Ulamog -1/-1 making it a 9/9, but Ulamog will still exile cards.

---

[Spells](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Spell) are only ever cards (or copies of cards) that are on the stack. Abilities never count as spells.

[Activated abilities](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Activated_ability) also have a specific formatting you can recognise them by:

> **602.1.** Activated abilities have a cost and an effect. They are written as “[Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]”

An example of activated abilities is found on [Elvish Mystic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElvish%20Mystic%5d): note the presence of a cost (tap Elvish Mystic), colon **:**, and effect (add green mana). An activated ability has all three of these; an ability without these is not an activated ability.

Comment: It might be useful to explain what an activated ability actually is too

Comment: @diego Thanks, good suggestion. I've expanded the answer to say what those are.